# Java application first run and preload class issues

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, initialization, loading

My REST service application is very slow the first time it is solicited.
Apparently the problem is linked with the loading of the java classes and the initialization.

Is there a way to force the application to initialize itself without waiting to the first call ?

Thank you for your time.
Julien.

Comment: How is your REST services initalised? I would have thought the web container initalised and wired up everything before hand. I would suggest you profile your application.

Comment: My web service is a Spring framework based (Spring security, data, ....), ibean injected into my API, on a tomcat web container.

Comment: Then it should have started and wired everything when application first started up. You need to profile what took time when for the first request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preloading java classes/libraries at jar startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677739/preloading-java-classes-libraries-at-jar-startup)